# Not able to connect to MySQL database from Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have started learning electron js application development, so I have created a simple electron js application and I am trying to get data from the MySQL database display it on the HTML page.
In the developer console, inside the MySQL connection object state is disconnected.
**am able to get an alert which is renderer.js file and dbmgr.js file**.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myfirstelectronapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first electron app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Pradeep",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^17.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <h1>My First Electron application get started</h1>
  <div id="names"></div>  
  <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
```

**renderer.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  alert('renderer.js');
  let names = window.api.getData();
  console.log(names);
  let divId = document.getElementById("names");
  let namestring = names.join("<br> /");
  divId.innerHTML = namestring;
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const dmmgr=require("./models/dbmgr");
const {contextBridge}=require('electron');

const getData=()=>{
   return dmmgr.getData();
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api",{
    getData : getData
})
```

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js')
        }
    })
    win.loadFile("index.html");
}
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') app.quit();
})
```

**dbmgr.js**

code connect mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Add the credentials to access your database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root', // or the original password : 'apaswword'
    database: 'vs_users_temp'
});

// connect to mysql
connection.connect(function (err) {
    // in case of error
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error "+err.code);
        console.log("Error "+err.sqlMessage);
    }
});

exports.getData = () => {
    alert('dbmgr.js');
    console.log(connection);
    // Perform a query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM user';
    connection.query($query, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Query succesfully executed", rows);
        return rows;
    });
}


// Close the connection
connection.end(function () {
    // The connection has been closed
});
```

Comment: In your `renderer.js` file, don't forget to insert `names` into your `document.getElementById` line. IE: `let divId = document.getElementById("names");`. If your database is not connecting, you may need to show some code regarding that as well (with any usernames and passwords removed). IE: `/models/dbmgr.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to render data within your `index.html` file immediately after it has loaded then you could use [`win.webContents.send(channel, ...args);`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) once the [application is ready](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#event-ready) and the [window is loaded](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options). This is like pushing the data from the main thread instead of pulling it from the render thread (via your existing `preload.js` script).

Additionally, implementing concrete functions within your `preload.js` script can be difficult to understand and implement successfully. Instead, I find the approach of using the `preload.js` script as a gateway to communicate between the main thread and render thread(s) via the use of channel names to be much simpler to understand and implement.

---

In this `preload.js` script, one only needs to specify their [whitelisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting) channel name(s). These channel names are used to identify within the main thread and render threads defined lines of communication (with optional data).

In the below preload file I have defined the channel name `db:getData`. You can use any channel name you like.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'db:getData' // Channel name        
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Once the application is ready and the window has been loaded, send a message using the channel name `db:getData` to the render thread along with the accompanying result set from the database.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

const dbmgr = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'dbmgr'); // Include your dbmgr module

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('db:getData', dbmgr.getData()); }) // Send data to render
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

For simplicity, I have the Mysql `connect` and `end` functions within the called `getData()` function (which is exported for use in the `main.js` file).

> Though I haven't used the `mysql` package before, I believe [pooling connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections) is highly recommended.

`dbmgr.js` (main thread)

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Add the credentials to access your database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root', // or the original password : 'apaswword'
    database: 'vs_users_temp'
});

function getData() => {
    // connect to mysql
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        // in case of error
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error ' + err.code);
            console.log('Error ' + err.sqlMessage);
        }
    });
    
    console.log(connection); // Testing
    
    // Perform a query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM user';
    
    connection.query($query, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('An error ocurred performing the query.');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log('Query succesfully executed', rows); // Testing

        // Close the connection
        connection.end(function () {});
        
        return rows;
    });
}

module.exports = { getData }
```

---

For the sake of simplicity I have included your `renderer.js` code within your `index.html` `<script>` tags.

> Placing your `<script>` tag(s) (whether it is importing or inline) just below the closing `</body>` tag is best practice.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>My First Electron application get started</h1>
      <div id="names"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.ipcRender.receive('db:getData', (names) => {
                console.log(names); // Testing
                
                let divId = document.getElementById('names');
                let namestring = names.join("<br> /");
                divId.innerHTML = namestring;
            });        
    </script>
</html>
```